# Need Function That Translates Velocity to Rotation

Tags: java, math, physics

I have a flying object and I want to point it in the direction it's heading. What I have is the object's current x and y velocity and the ability to rotate the image. So what I need is a function that takes the x and y velocity and gives me the degrees I need to rotate by. This is the function I have so far:

```
private float getRotation(float x, float y)
{
    if (x == 0 && y > 0)
        return 90;
    else if (x == 0 && y < 0)
        return 270;
    else if (x > 0 && y == 0)
        return 0;
    else if (x < 0 && y == 0)
        return 180;
    else if (x == 0 && y == 0)
        return 0;
    else
        return ????;
}
```

What I have is so far correct, except where the `????` is, the most important part. Anyone know how to make this work?

This might be more of a math problem, but it involves programming, so if this is on the wrong forum I apologize.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`Math.atan2()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1,5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#atan2%28double,%20double%29)

Comment: Worth mentioning that this replaces *all* the OP's cases. I.e. it takes care of all special cases itself, including infinites that the OP doesn't deal with etc.

Answer (score 1):

I had to do something similar for a game I wrote, I end up using polar coordinates.. here is the result:

```
if (velocity.x > 0 && velocity.y >= 0)
    angle =  atan(velocity.y/velocity.x);
else if (velocity.x > 0 && velocity.y < 0)
    angle = atan(velocity.y/velocity.x) - 2.0f*PI;
else if (velocity.x < 0)
    angle = atan(velocity.y/velocity.x) + PI;
else if (velocity.x == 0 && velocity.y > 0)
    angle = PI/2.0f;
else if (velocity.x == 0 && velocity.y < 0)
    angle = 3.0f*PI/2.0f;
```

I was still young when I wrote this piece, `atan2` is enough actually, but I did want to have fun by browsing my old source code..

Just a side note: don't use equal comparisons (`==`) with floats, always check with a threshold (eg. `abs(x) < 0.01f`), just because as you know, they are not precise as you would like them to be.